# what are the differences between adding a link to a publishing page using; [[PageName]] & insert link from address & insert link from sharepoint

Tags: 2013, development, publishing-page, hyperlink, enterprise-wiki

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection inside SharePoint server 2013. now I want to add a link to another wiki page inside the same site collection, but I find that there are 3 main ways of doing so as follow:-

1. using the [[ ]] appraoch
2. edit the wiki page >> Insert >> Link >> from address >> type the full url of the destination page such as `http://servername/sites/siteA/Pages/Page1.aspx`
3. edit the wiki page >> Insert >> Link >> from sharepoint >> type the full url of the destination page such as `http://servername/sites/siteA/Pages/Page1.aspx`

now for me, the three approaches will do the following:-

1. they will automatically update their URL in case I change the URL for the destination page. so if i change the URL for the destination page from `page1.aspx` to `page2.aspx` then the 3 links will automatically update their URL to match `page2.aspx`.

now when I edit my wiki page which contains the above 3 links, and I view the Page source (in edit mode) I got the following:-

```
<p>[[page2|page1]]</p>
<p>
   <a href="/sites/siteA/Pages/page2.aspx">test</a></p>
<p>
   <a href="/sites/siteA/Pages/page2.aspx">test</a></p>
<p>&#160;</p>
```

also when I am in the view mode, I checked the generated markup for the 3 links and I got the following:-

```
<p><a class="ms-wikilink" id="0::page2|page1" href="/sites/siteA/Pages/page2.aspx">test</a></p>
<p><a href="/sites/siteA/Pages/page2.aspx">test</a></p>
<p><a href="/sites/siteA/Pages/page2.aspx">test</a></p>
```

so now I am totally confused if we need to communicate which approach our end-users should follow to link different wiki pages? or at the end the 3 approaches will have the same result, and it is a matter of preferences ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have Wikis, I suggest stick to the Wiki format with the square brackets - I mean, after all - it is Wiki, right? :)
Plus, you'll get updated title of the target page, when it changes, not just the URL.

Other two options exists, because they are basic features of SharePoint and are used in all kind of sites (team/publishing).

Comment: sorry but i did not get your answer correctly .. what do you mean by "_after all - it is Wiki, right? :) _" ?? and i think the three approaches will update their URL in-case the target page urll is changed, and not just the first appraoch..

Comment: can you adivce more on my comment?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough...
I mean that - since you have wiki site, I think it is best if you stick with the wiki format of the links. It looks to me as this is the most reliable solution in terms of change management and future-proof of eventual migrations to newer SharePoint version or even export to another wiki system.

Comment: And I wasn't correct about the title. I thought (wrong memory from another wiki platform I guess) that when you change the title of the page, this will modify the text of the links in other pages too (because the URL is based on the title), but I was wrong about that.

Comment: yes if i use the [[PageTitle]] appraoch to build a link to another wiki page,, and i change the destination page url & Title then the [[Pagetitle]] text will not get the new title,, but the link will be referencing the new url..